# How are aeronautical procedures created in the US?

Tags: usa, faa, regulations, aeronautical-charts

In creating new procedures for an airport, does someone from the FAA go to an airport, examine all their information, and choose what kind of approach/departure (for example) will be created? Or do airport officials advise the FAA (chart creators)?

Comment: Are you asking about commercial aviation, or general aviation?

Comment: I want to know the algorithm why procedures changes, and how they created, especially commercial

Comment: things don't usually change unless it's to avoid dangerous situations, these are very often revealed by accidents.

Comment: You don't mention where you are which is important as in most locations this is the responsibility of the governement (or its designated agency/contractor).  You might want to start with this FAA [Division](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/afs/afs400/afs420/) responsible for procedure development for the US.

Comment: The guidelines that they use to develop procedures are contained in FAA Order 8260.3C United States Standard for Terminal Instrument Procedures (TERPS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> does a worker go to an airport and monitors all information, and choose what kind of approach/departure (for example) will be? Or do airport workers advise regulators (charts creators)?

Yes. :)

Airport/airspace procedures are mainly created by a country's local aviation authority, so if you want an instrument approach to your private airstrip in the US you would contact [AFS-420, the FAA's procedures branch](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/afs/afs400/afs420/), probably through someone at your local FSDO, and ask them to work with you to develop the procedure.
The Procedures people will survey the approach and design a procedure that makes sure you won't hit anything on the ground, and ensure that your procedure won't conflict with other existing procedures.

Once the procedure is designed they'll test-fly it - that's done [by another group](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/avn/flightinspection/) - and if everything checks out they'll publish charts for it.

Once published the FAA will periodically re-evaluate then procedure, both through flight checks and other feedback (if your new procedure is generating a lot of noise complaints for example the FAA will work with you to reduce the impact).